# Size control on MDI child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

In my application there are two forms.

```
MDIParentForm
Child form
```

Child form contains a panel. Here is the code:

```
private void ChildForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (this.WindowState.Equals(FormWindowState.Maximized))
    {
        this.lPanel.Height *= 2;
        this.lPanel.Width *= 2;
    }
if (this.WindowState.Equals(FormWindowState.Normal) 
         || this.WindowState.Equals (FormWindowState.Minimized))
    {
        this.lPanel.Height /= 2;
        this.lPanel.Width /= 2;
    }

}
```

Now, I maximize the child form. And minimize the MDIParent Form from the task bar. Now when I restore the MDIParent, the Panel (i.e. in the ChildForm) expands to double as in code. Controls in child form must not expand. TIRED OF THIS.

Comment: This cannot work, the SizeChanged event runs a lot more often than you hope.  You'll need to write smarter code.  Only expand the panel if the form's ClientSize is big enough.  Restore the size when it gets too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is automatic re-sizing, why don't you use anchors?
Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anchor property keeps control's relative position. I don't think it resize the control.

Comment: It also does re-size also. If you anchor a control to say left and right. Then on original container re-size the control will expand left and right. Same for top and bottom. And if you want it to expand in all directions, you can anchor it to all directions.

Comment: Anchor resize the control relative to the form size. But I want to expand to particular value. Anchor does not work there I think.